# Joi validating a Set?

Tags: typescript, validation, casting, set, joi

In typescript I have a set of allowed platforms, represented as a set of a union:

```
type Platform = 'WEB' | 'APP' | 'MAIL'
type AllowedPlatforms = Set<Platform>
```

I want to validate an array and cast it to a set using Joi:

```
const validPlatforms = [Joi.string().valid('WEB'), Joi.string().valid('APP'), Joi.string().valid('MAIL')]

const validatePlatform = Joi.array().items(validPlatforms)
e
```

Now, the validator should check that it's an array where each item is one of three values. According to the documentation there should be a cast function so that I can cast it to a set afterwards but I can not figure how to use it (https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.8#anycastto). I tried `Joi.array().cast('set')` but Typescript complains that cast does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast exists in version 16.1.8 of @hapi/joi, however I was using the package joi which does not include cast. Hence why it was not working.